# Onclick event in JS shows results for a second before automatically resetting form

Tags: javascript, onclick, forms, onsubmit

This is a simple quiz/questionnaire, that'll display results of the quiz on submission. It shows the results, but only for about half a second before resetting the page. I would also like for the page to show an alert if the user says they're under 18 when the quiz is submitted; it wouldn't keep them from seeing the answers, but just giving them a message.

```
    function checkAge() {
    if(age<18) {
        alert("Always make sure you have adult supervision while caring for and handling any venomous arachnid.");
    } }

function generateAnswers() {

var choice1score = 0;
var choice2score = 0;
var choice3score = 0;
var choice4score = 0;
}

var chosenAnswers = document.getElementsByTagName('result');

for (i=0; i<chosenAnswers.length; i++) {

    if (chosenAnswers[i].checked) {
  // add 1 to that choice's score
    if (chosenAnswers[i].value == 'choice1') {
    choice1score = choice1score + 1;
    }
      if (chosenAnswers[i].value == 'choice2') {
    choice2score = choice2score + 1;
    }
    if (chosenAnswers[i].value == 'choice3') {
    choice3score = choice3score + 1;
    }
    if (chosenAnswers[i].value == 'choice4') {
    choice4score = choice4score + 1;
    }

    }
}

var maxscore = Math.max(choice1score,choice2score,choice3score,choice4score);

var resultBox = document.getElementById('result');
    if (choice1score == maxscore) { 
    resultBox.innerHTML = "Asian Forest Scorpion"
    }
    if (choice2score == maxscore) { 
    resultBox.innerHTML = "Deathstalker Scorpion"
    }
    if (choice3score == maxscore) { 
    resultBox.innerHTML = "Desert Hairy Scorpion"
    }
    if (choice4score == maxscore) { 
    resultBox.innerHTML = "Emperor Scorpion"
}

}
```

This is where I put the code:
https://codepen.io/cryceks/pen/vjgzOZ

Comment: You no doubt just need to use `event.preventDefault();` to stop the default behaviour of the `form` tag which is to submit/post data.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This prevents the webpage from reloading and therefore clearing form data

Comment: Does it matter where I put that? I've never used event.preventDefault(); before, and every answer I find requires me to use jQuery, which I'm not using for this code.

Comment: After you take data in, so after a .click() event or .submit() anything that has user interaction with the page, you need to pass event as a parameter though

Comment: I tried inserting it in the onClick event, but it didn't return anything at all once I put it there. Could you provide me with an example?